# Upload File to Firebase Storage using Admin SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

According to the [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-nodejs), I have to pass the filename to the function in order to upload a file.

```js
// Uploads a local file to the bucket
await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
  // Support for HTTP requests made with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
  gzip: true,
  metadata: {
    // Enable long-lived HTTP caching headers
    // Use only if the contents of the file will never change
    // (If the contents will change, use cacheControl: 'no-cache')
    cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
  },
});
```

I am using Firebase Admin SDK (Nodejs) in my server side code and clients send file in form-data which i get as File Objects. How then do i upload this when the function accepts only filename leading to filepath.

I want to be able to do something like this

```js
app.use(req: Request, res: Response) {
 const file = req.file;
// upload file to firebase storage using admin sdk
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Since the Firebase Admin SDK just wraps the Cloud SDK, you can use the [Cloud Storage node.js API documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/) as a reference to see what it can do.

You don't have to provide a local file.  You can also upload using node streams.  There is a method [File.createWriteStream()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File#createWriteStream) which gets you a WritableStream to work with.  There is also [File.save()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File#save) which accepts multiple kinds of things, including a Buffer.  There are examples of using each method [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/2334).

Comment: Url not working

Comment: fixed to point to [https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/)

Comment: You could also refer to [https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/main/samples/streamFileUpload.js](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/main/samples/streamFileUpload.js) for stream file upload

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this question while uploading image from URL here's my solution by uploading buffer.

```
const fileContent = await fetch(url)
const buffer = await fileContent.arrayBuffer()
const bf = Buffer.from(buffer)
const id = uuid()
const bucket = storage.bucket()

const file = bucket.file('filePath' + id + '.png')

const up = await file.save(bf, {
                 contentType: 'image/png',
                 cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
           })
```

Comment: There is conflicting advice about where to place cacheControl. When I tested this, I found that cacheControl needs to be nested inside metadata: {} or else it does not seem to work. So the above example should be: file.save(bf, {contentType: 'image/png', metadata: {cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000'}})

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of uploading an image to your `Firebase Storage` from an existing web url using `Firebase Admin` Node.js:

```
var firebase = require("firebase-admin");
const uuid = require('uuid-v4');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const storageUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/your-app-name.appspot.com/o"

const uploadImageFromUrl = async (remoteimageurl, filename) => {
   let res = await fetch(remoteimageurl)
   const buffer = await res.arrayBuffer()
   const bf = Buffer.from(buffer)
   const token =  uuid();
   const metadata = {
      metadata: {
         firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: token,
      },
      contentType: 'image/png',
      cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
   };
   await firebase.storage().bucket().file(`${filename}`).save(bf, {
      metadata: metadata,
   });
   const finalUrl = `${storageUrl}/${filename}?alt=media&token=${token}`
   return finalUrl;
}

const catImageUrl = "https://icatcare.org/app/uploads/2018/07/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png"
uploadImageFromUrl(catImageUrl, "test.jpg"); //example
```

And here is and example of uploading an image that is saved to your local machine:

```
var firebase = require("firebase-admin");
const uuid = require('uuid-v4');
const storageUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/your-app-name.appspot.com/o"

const uploadImageFromLocal = async (localUrl, filename) => {
   const token =  uuid();
   const metadata = {
      destination: `foo/sub/${filename}`,
      metadata: {
         firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: token,
      },
      contentType: 'image/png',
      cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
   };
   await firebase.storage().bucket().upload(`${localUrl}`, metadata);
   let finalUrl = `${storageUrl}/foo/sub/${filename}?alt=media&token=${token}`
   return finalUrl;
}

const localImageUrl = "foo/sub/cat.jpg";
uploadImageFromLocal(localImageUrl, "test.jpg"); //example
```

Answer (score -1):

what you should do is use the built-in function

let's say you receive the file as imageDoc in the client side and

```
 const imageDoc = e.target.files[0]
```

in node, you can now get a URL path to the object as

```
 const imageDocUrl = URL.createObjectURL(imageDoc)
```

so your final code will be

```
    // Uploads a local file to the bucket
    await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(imageDocUrl, {
        // Support for HTTP requests made with "Accept-Encoding: gzip"
        gzip: true,
         metadata: {
           // Enable long-lived HTTP caching headers
           // Use only if the contents of the file will never change
           // (If the contents will change, use cacheControl: 'no-cache')
           cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
     },
});
```

Comment: i tried doing this but i am getting error `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'E:\Server\blob:http:\localhost:3000\34544810-4aa6-4070-adf8-15c636b92c29'` is there any other way?

Comment: @Billjesh you can try 1st saving the image on a temp folder on your server then use the method above to upload the image but you'll have to replace `imageDocUrl` with the path to the image you just saved locally