# Firebase admin when uploading files to storage through url: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

So I am trying to make a music app where people can upload music there. First, the client takes file and changes it to object url like this:

```js
const track_src = URL.createObjectURL(track);
data.track_src = track_src;
await Req.post("/api/u/music/upload", data)
```

After that, the server receives the data and object url and uploads it to Firebase storage:

```js
//track_src is the object url

await st.bucket(sid).upload(track_src, {
    gzip: true,
    metadata: {
      cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
    },
})
```

But I get error that says:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'E:\Server\blob:http:\localhost:3000\91e53bb5-abf2-46b4-bd0c-268b242e93f3'

Comment: I suggest you have a look at [the documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload). You're trying to pass your blob URI as the `pathString` parameter ~ _"The fully qualified path to the file you wish to upload to your bucket."_

Comment: @Phil I had got idea to do that from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64752587/14786214

Comment: @Phil is it possible to upload the file from blob URI?

Comment: I don't know, I've never used it. If there is a way though, it won't be via the `upload()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible. There are basically 2 methods of uploading files in Storage, you either have to :

- Use the `bucket().upload()` method to upload, **which accepts the path to your local file as the `pathString` parameter**, so you need the actual file for this, not a url. This is the ideal option if you have the file stored locally and given the information you shared this might be the way to go for you. You can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59800519/12857703) for more information.
- Use the `bucket().file()` to create an empty file in Storage and then use the `file.createWriteStream()` method to get a stream that can write to the file content. This can be a valid solution if you have the file in memory.

I would suggest you to take a look at this [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html) for the methods offered for the bucket class and this [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html) for the methods offered for the file class.

Comment: ya researched about it, but i could not get any information about uploading file using blob url. Thanks for the answer though.